# get the size of list when using logic:iterate

Tags: loops, struts, logic

I have the following code:

```
    <logic:iterate id="paymean" name="JstSelectPaymentInfoForm" property="barsOption.list" collection= indexId="barInd" type="com.amdocs.css.jst.singleorder.checkout.view.JstPaymentInfoBar">

        <%
            if(barInd!=sizeOftheList-1)){
                          .
                          . 
                          .
            }
        %>
```

I want that instead of `sizeOftheList`, I'll have an expression that will give me the size of the list that I am iterating over.
I am using JSP scriptlets and struts

Answer (score -1):

First, never use scriplets in your JSP pages.

[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202)

Second, try this -

```
<c:set var="count" value="0" scope="page" />      
<logic:iterate id="paymean" name="JstSelectPaymentInfoForm" property="barsOption.list" collection= indexId="barInd" type="com.amdocs.css.jst.singleorder.checkout.view.JstPaymentInfoBar">
  <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}" scope="page"/>
</logic:iterate>
//see the value of the count variable 
${count}
```